# Tumblr API returns 401 Unauthorized for followers method

Tags: python, api, oauth, tumblr

I'm using [this](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr) Python Tumblr API to retrieve the followers of a blog on Tumblr.

However, I get the following error:

```
>>> client.followers('adamgalla.tumblr.com')
{u'meta': {u'status': 401, u'msg': u'Not Authorized'}, u'response': []}
```

When I run the same query on my own blog, I get a successful JSON response.

Does the Tumblr API only grant you blog information for your own account?

Comment: Have tried using it how the docs suggest: `client.followers('adamgalla')`?

Comment: Yes, the {base-hostname} parameter can be in standard or custom mode. I don't think that's the issue

Comment: @Mark I feel your guess is correct. You can only get `followers` for the authorised account.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are for **owner**. Your **oauth token** should be matched with **adamgalla account**. Check the `quene()` method also.